# What Gerber File Viewer is This?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, gerber

[image]

PCBWay sent me this image while trying to troubleshoot my circuit board file content not showing up. I want to know if this program is available so I can download/buy it to troubleshoot my output gerber files without waiting for them to do it for me. Does anyone recognise this program, or can at least identify what it is built on? If not, I suppose the program is proprietary...

Comment: hm, why not ask PCBWay? They'll tell you...

Comment: @Marcus Muller They have been very non-cooperative. They did not say that the viewer is proprietary, but they did say "We use our own gerber viewer, send us the files and we will look over them." This seems more like a marketing tactic, which I do not blame them for, but their online preview is trash and filled with errors, I must see how my output files actually look.

Comment: In that case... I cropped the image to a few of the icons from the actions menu bar, but reverse image searches (bing, google) revealed nothing; given the color scheme, this might really be software specific to the Chinese market. Well, if it can't be helped: I'm pretty happy with  `gerbv` from the gEda toolchain, and nearly as happy with `gerbview` from kiCad. Both are free software.

Comment: Vote with your wallet. Tell PCWay that my project is not important enough to them so I will recognize their recommendation and take my PCB fabrication project elsewhere.

Comment: It looks like Mentor Graphics Valor $200K production programming packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recognize the software.  Its called CAM350.  I use it to view my gerbers before sending them out.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need their Gerber viewer. Gerbers are used for a reason: they are standardized so it doesn't (or rather, shouldn't) matter which Gerber viewer you use.

I use DFM Now. It's a free Gerber viewer. Go File > Open Folder (Gerber/NC) and select the folder all your Gerbers are in.

You should have never sent your PCB off without viewing it in a Gerber viewer to begin with. PCB layout software sometimes does unexpected things when producing Gerber files; Often due to user error, but sometimes seemingly due to bugs.